# Как записать в переменную тег, если у него два класса?

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<li class="globalFrameProduct not-avail  " data-pos="top" style="">
```

а вот мой не рабочий вариант:

```
var notAvail = document.querySelector('.globalFrameProduct not-avail  ');
```

как записать именно по этим двум классам `globalFrameProduct not-avail`  ?

Comment: спсб. за вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var notAvail = document.querySelector('.globalFrameProduct.not-avail');
```

Дополнительно по селекторам https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

https://webref.ru/css/selector/multiclass

Comment: спсб. за ответ, даже и не знал, что есть такая возможность